# Using sed with backslash in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I get a syntax error when using

```
script{ 
    // remove single quote from .env file
    sh 'sed -i s/\'//g .env' 
}
```

in a jenkisfile.

> Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
>   script returned exit code 2

How can I escape this sed shell command in Jenkins groovy script?
Is there any other alternative to remove all single quotes from a text file?

Answer (score 1):

The general issue is both groovy and the shell are handling escape characters. You need to escape the backslash, so use `\\'` instead of `\'`

```
script{ 
    // remove single quote from .env file
    sh 'sed -i s/\\'//g .env' 
}
```

Note: if you want to pass a literal `\`, you need to pass `\\\\`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the backslash appearantly does not escape the single quote. However you can just use double quotes like this:

```
script {
    // remove single quote from .env file
    sh "sed -i s/'//g .env"
}
```